AWS Glue Python Jobs VS AWS Glue Spark Jobs
I have a usecase where I have to create an AWS Glue ETL job to update data stored in S3 Objects to an existing table in DDB. Few properties to be considered are :
Currently the dataset is approx 40 MB large.
Transformation may involve:

selecting objects on the basis of timestamp.
Updating already existing rows if duplicate objects have been created.
creating new rows for newly created objects.
filtering out only few attributes to be stored in the destination table.

Another usecase include a bit complex transformation :

getting a new attribute from the already existing data and such transformation may include grouping rows on the basis of partition key, then comparing each row of one group to each row of all other groups

I have to decide between Python jobs and spark jobs. Everywhere it is mentioned that AWS Glue Python shell jobs are better suited for small or medium-sized datasets and otherwise AWS Glue Spark jobs. Can someone specify in numbers, what is the approximate value of datasets which we should be considering for selecting AWS Glue Python shell jobs rather than spark jobs?

You are right, both can be used for data processing. It is also recommended to use just Python jobs if the simple set of transformations are required and one doesn't need horizontal or vertical scaling for the compute. There is no official numbers provided by AWS. I have tried processing couple of GBs data using python jobs but the performance was relatively lower than Spark jobs.
There are various factors to impact the job performance i.e. code optimization, sequence of transformations, profiling etc.
One of the known key limitation with Python Jobs is:

It uses default 0.0625 DPU and can be set to maximum 1 DPU(~16 GB
memory and 4 vCPUs) whereas Spark Jobs require minimum 2 DPUs. That
limits the possibility of performing complex transformation with
higher compute capacity.

According to offical documentation, there is a comparison chart as well describing some key differences:
If your job is simple and can be solved using vanilla python, you should choose that. Also consider using packages i.e. Pandas, PyArrow etc. for performance improvement.


Yes, I have seen this comparison chart. Thank you for your response.
